# DataGridView header alignment

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am using vb.net 2005. I want one clarification for datagridview.

I use the following property to set the alignment of header text:

```
DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter
```

This property applies to all header cells. I only want to change one headers alignment property.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To change just the one header cell you need to select the column you want from the DataGridView columns collection.

```
dataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter;

dataGridView1.Columns("ColumnName").HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
```

I've shown two examples - one using the column index in the columns collection, the other using the name given to the column.

Each column in the DataGridView then has a HeaderCell property, with a Style.Alignment that can be set with a value from the DataGridViewContentAlignment enum.

One additional thing to note is that these alignments are affected by the sorting glyph in the column. If the alignment does not appear how you expect, the code below can sometimes resolve the issue by removing the sorting glyph.

```
dataGridView1.Columns(0).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
```

Comment: The sorting glyph reference solved my problem. I suppose it was only hidden, but it wasn't allowing the text to be completely near the right border. Thanks!

Comment: The mention of the SortMode issue was important, had wondered before why it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

There is a property `HeaderCell` on the column object which allow you to access the style:

```
dataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment 
  = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter
```

Answer (score 0):

For column **headers** you can do this

```
DataGrid d = new DataGrid();
d.Columns[0].HeaderStyle.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Bottom;
```

For **cell content** you can do this

```
DataGrid d = new DataGrid();
d.Columns[0].ItemStyle.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Bottom;
```

EDIT:
Just realised that you were asking about GridViews - This will be the same for that too

```
eg
GridView gv = new GridView ();
gv.Columns[0].ItemStyle.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Bottom;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i want datagrid view not datagrid.

datagridview not having this property. please help me sir

Comment: sorry question was tagged with 'DataGrid' - also you might like to accept a few answers to encourage others to help you

Answer (score 0):

datagridview.Columns(linti).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter

here linti means columnno or id

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter
```

to

```
DataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```